# installing sshpass on amazon linux AMI based ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, yum, rackspace-cloud

I am planning to automate aws-rackspace server migration. I am following the official rackspace documentation(https://github.com/cloudnull/InstanceSync/blob/master/rsrsyncLive.sh) which uses rsync to migrate. I have modified the code to use sshpass to dynamically provide login password while making an SSH connection to the remote server.

```
sshpass -p "YOUR_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@IPAddress
```

But I am facing trouble installing sshpass package.

```
Debian based Distros - Installed Successfully
CentOS - Installed Successfully
Redhat - Package not found (yum list available | grep sshpass) 
Amazon Linux -  Package not found (yum list available | grep sshpass)
```

I even tried 'yum update' and then 'yum -y install sshpass' but it didn't work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to manually download source code of [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/),after that

```
Extract it and cd into the directory
./configure
sudo make install
```

Note :: If you do not find make then you can run following command for installing make

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Answer (score 8):

On Amazon Linux 2 I do it like this

```sh
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum install sshpass
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this answer on [another stack overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129835/sshpass-command-not-found-error), but it worked for me when `yum install sshpass` was returning

> "No package sshpass available"

when trying to install on an AWS instance.

Command:

```
yum --enablerepo=epel -y install sshpass
```

Answer (score 3):

I thought a little bit of details may help to get this done quickly.

This is where sshpass can be downloaded from (search for any recent updates): http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/files/sshpass/1.05/ 
And from the page get the URL for the download as below

```
$ wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/files/sshpass/1.05/sshpass-1.05.tar.gz/download # on your amazon instance, to download using command line / terminal; this will get you a file named "download"

$ mv download sshpass-1.05.tar.gz # note this is the name as in the URL above

$ gunzip sshpass-1.05.tar.gz
$ tar xvf sshpass-1.05.tar

$ cd sshpass-1.05

$ sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" # in case configure & make (next 2 commands) does not work, else dont run this command

$ sudo ./configure

$ sudo make install

$ sudo -s
# which sshpass #sudo -s and check if sshpass is in the path; on amazon RHEL, for me the root did not have /usr/local/bin in its path; so you may want to set the path appropriately (echo $PATH), or copy sshpass to one of the $PATH directories
```

Comment: Helpful addition to the accepted answer. However, I would point out that ./configure does not need sudo. You probably should also run first make without sudo to compile and when that is done, run sudo make install.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Download](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=sshpass&srodzaj=3) rpm file
2. # su -
3. # rpm -ivh [pass to your rpm file]

Answer (score 0):

On Ansible Master (Amazon Linux) Before:

```
linux1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

After exection the following:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel -y install sshpass
```

Ping worked!

```
linux1 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```